# How does the DOM initiate javascript calls though there seem to be no specific calls?

Tags: jquery, html, css, dom

The HTML source does not have any specific calls to javascript functions but the DOM lists such calls. For instance, the code in source is : 
    **`<div title="About" data-options="iconCls:'icon-ok'" style="overflow:auto;padding:10px;">`**
which translates in the DOM to: 
    **

```
<div class="panel" style="width: 498px;">
    <div class="panel-header accordion-header accordion-header-selected"    style="height: 16px; width: 488px;">
    <div class="panel-title panel-with-icon">About </div>
    <div class="panel-icon icon-ok"> </div>
    <div class="panel-tool">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="panel-tool-collapse" style="display: none;"></a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="accordion-collapse"></a>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div title="" data-options="iconCls:'icon-ok'" style="overflow: auto; padding: 10px; display: block; width: 478px; height: 170px;" class="panel-body accordion-body">
```

**

[the above is a specific example from the jeasyui demos]

How is the call to javascript initiated? Are the extra classes added only by such calls? (i tried to explore the minified js version but could not get a clue as to its actual processing).

Comment: What Javascript are you talking about?

Comment: Probably by DOM replacement? The JavaScript, upon DOM ready or the window load event, uses a selector, sniffs out your original element and does some complicated DOM manipulation to arrive at the generated markup.

Comment: The Javascript code could contain something like `$(document).ready()`. This runs code automatically after the DOM is loaded.

Comment: Ok, this is the demo: http://www.jeasyui.com/demo/main/index.php?plugin=Accordion&theme=default&dir=ltr&pitem=     There is no specific jquery functions in the HTML itself.

Comment: Many libraries do this same thing...bootstrap is another example. You add the classes and attributes they suggest and the library looks for them on each page load and manipulates into whatever widget it is  based on options in attributes. Can look through bootstrap source for general idea what they do

Comment: Thanks charlie, the idea seems to be getting clearer. How can we really explore its execution?  The firebug and web inspector were not of much help.

Comment: If all you want is theory and you can't find a source version for that library...look at how bootstrap does it. Lots of plugins do it too...like cycle2 slide show. Not sure what exactly you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

The JavaScript file: easyui.min.js is wrapped with a self invoking function:

`(function($){/*body of code*/})(jQuery);`

By simply inserting the file into your document, the JavaScript automatically calls itself and runs when the file loads.

You can view the source of their code here: http://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/jquery.easyui.min.js

When the script runs, it looks for specific classes that you've put into your HTML and wraps their logic around it e.g. 'accordion-header'.

Comment: the IIFE has nothing to do with it. They use a load handler just like anyone else. All that IIFE does is insulate their code